# click on button during test run opens a blank window selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I'm having a bit difficulties with Chrome driver and Selenium, I have selenium.support version 3.141.0, chrome driver version 2.43.0 and Google Chrome version 71.0.3578.98.

During a test run I click on a button which opens a new window, but for some reason the window is blank instead of the site that should have been loaded. I tried to reproduced it manually but it doesn't happen except from test run.

Do you have any explanation or know the reason for this occurrence?

Comment: does it throw any exception?

Comment: it throws exception 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' because i try to find an element in the window

Comment: I have had the same issue in the past can you provide your code and html?

Comment: @MosheSlavin html: <html><head></head><body></body></html>.   code: Window.WaitForElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(@id, 'someId')]")).click();. window is a wrapper to IWebDriver

Comment: sometimes your click is not on the element that invokes the rerender to the new page...

Comment: try using the method I have shown below...

Comment: formatting and typos

Comment: The script is probably going too fast and the element that you click to open a new window is not properly formed. Try putting a breakpoint on the element click and let the page fully load then let it run. Does it work?

Comment: @JeefC it does work

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue a few times...

What I have found was that the element that I'm trying to click is not the element that actually invokes the rerender to next page...

**My solution**

So... to get to the parent element I have used the `parent` method in XPath.

for example, if I am looking for an element with `id='x_d'` so I use: `Window.WaitForElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(@id, 'x')]")).click();`

Now the problem is that the Invoker is the parent so to access the parent `a`  I'll use:

```
Window.WaitForElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(@id, 'x')]//parent :: a")).click();
```

Hope this helps you!